# Two canvases as textures for plane in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to render two canvases as textures on a plane in three.js. I created an array with two `MeshBasicMaterial` and did the following

```
texture2 = new THREE.Texture(c1);
texture3 = new THREE.Texture(c3); 
var mat1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture2 });
var mat2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture3 });    

materials.push(mat1);
materials.push(mat2);

mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ));
scene2.add(mesh2);  

renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas:c2});
renderer2.setSize(c2.width, c2.height);

document.body.appendChild(renderer2.domElement);
```

I created this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gr90mc4k/) to show my actual problem. The second texture isn't rendered on canvas2, but I want to show both textures on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reason**

The reason why the second texture is not rendered is because it doesn't know which faces to assign the first or second material to, so by default it gives the first material to all of them.

**Solution**

- Update `Three.js` to latest build (r76). You're are now running r54
- Loop through all faces and assign them a `materialIndex`([Face3](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Face3))
- Use `THREE.MultiMaterial` instead of `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial`:

  ```
  mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials ));
  ```

Comment: Thanks @leota, this is really helping me. This is me newest approach: http://jsbin.com/fufokunave/1/edit?js,output However I would like to "stack" the textures, as in overlaying one texture with the other. Could you edit your solution?

Comment: @Sincostan - You want the one on top to be transparent so you can see the other texture too?

Comment: Exactly. Overlay one canvas with the other transparent one.

Comment: @Sincostan - I think if I modify my answer it would not match with your initial issue, that has been  already solved. You should ask another question, maybe: "How to overlay texture maps in Three.js?".

Comment: It's just to help other users to easily find what they're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I did. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812886/how-to-overlay-texture-maps-in-three-js for possible answering.

Comment: Sure,I'll try to help you out